# Android emulator gives errors when running it

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have created an android virtual device and created a flutter project using android studio on Mac (M1). Then when I select my newly created device, it gives this error without running it..No idea on how this error tiggers..Need a help to solve this..!!!

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/lyang/install-qt/lib/libQt5CoreAndroidEmu.5.dylib 
Referenced from: /Users/$username/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/qemu-system-aarch64 Reason: image not found
```

[error-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IibyT.png)

Comment: Same here. Any progress in this issue?

Comment: @niels not still